# Eslint,prettier+airbnb style guide for react , It will not format based on the rules i gave in the .prettierrc

Tags: javascript, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

Here is .eslintrc.js file :

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
  },
  extends: ['airbnb', 'plugin:prettier/recommended'],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    ecmaVersion: 12,
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  plugins: ['react'],
  rules: {
    'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 'off',
  },
};
```

In the .prettierrc   i just give the following style:

```
{
    "tabWidth": 4
}
```

Right now , my code can detect error and auto fix the styling issue with default settings. However, it does not take any rules from prettier. It seems prettier does not work here.
In order to give customized rules for prettier I have to do change rules in .eslintrc.js. By doing this, I can format code with tabwith as 4.    Could anyone help me figure out why my previous way does not work. Which part did I set up incorrect?

```
    rules: {
        'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 'off',
        'prettier/prettier': [
            'error',
            {
                tabWidth: 4,
            },
        ],
    },
```

Here is my package.json file:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.23.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.23.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1"
  }
```

Comment: I had a similar issue, just that Prettier overwrote ESLint rules. The `prettier-eslint` package solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, It do solve my problem by install prettier-eslint